# Column Row Transpose in Oracle Sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have a simple query which give this result

[image]

And I want to modify it as follows. the Name column becomes the column headers and the studentID column becomes the 1st row

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH t AS
     (SELECT 1001 studentid, 'john' NAME FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1002, 'kane' FROM dual
     )
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT studentid, NAME FROM t)
pivot (max(studentid) for name in ('john' John, 'kane' Kane));
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks.  I am new to this oracle sql. I don't write many queries but  need to occasionally. Could you please explain the logic behind the transformation and your query

Comment: You may read using of `PIVOT` clause, see documentation and links eg: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html, http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php