# Multiple SELECT in INSERT INTO query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need a query that will sort data from Tab and put it into NewTab, which looks like this:

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and I've tried code:

```
INSERT INTO NewTab(Var1,Var2,Var3,DTime) VALUES (
    (SELECT Value FROM Tab WHERE VarName='Var1'),
    (SELECT Value FROM Tab WHERE VarName='Var2'),
    (SELECT Value FROM Tab WHERE VarName='Var3'),
    (SELECT DTime FROM Tab WHERE VarName='Var1')
    )
```

But server is returning and error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I'm quite new to SQL and I'll be grateful if someone help me with that.

Comment: Try the following suggestion:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107174/column-row-transpose-in-oracle-sql

Comment: This is how I did the transpose. Refer the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107174/column-row-transpose-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems to be trying to pivot the data. There are other ways to do it (i.e using PIVOT operator), but I guess that using old-school aggregate functions help us get a better idea of how data is processed:

```
SELECT DTime
, SUM(CASE WHEN varname = 'Var1' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [Var1]
, SUM(CASE WHEN varname = 'Var2' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [Var2]
, SUM(CASE WHEN varname = 'Var3' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS [Var3]
FROM Tab
GROUP BY DTime
```

Comment: It will not be as efficient as it could be (in your example, the trigger will fire 3 times), but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this !!

you could use a pivot operator

```
select * into newtab  from [dbo].[Tab]
pivot(
max(value)
for varname in([var1],[var2],[var3])
)as piv;
```